# How do I move pods to a new node pool/ instance group

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Gke cluster with one node pool attached

I want to make some changes to the node pool though- like adding tags, etc

So I created a new node pool with my new config and attached to the cluster. so now cluster has 2 node pools.

At this point I want to move the pods to the new node pool and destroy the old one

How is this process done? Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are multiple ways to move your pods to the new node pool.

One way is to steer your pods to the new node pool using a label selector in your pod spec, as described in the "More fun with node pools" in the [Google blog post that announced node pools](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-google-container-engine-gke-node-pools) (with the caveat that you need to forcibly terminate the existing pods for them to be rescheduled). This leaves all nodes in your cluster functional, and you can easily shift the pods back and forth between pools using the labels on the node pools (GKE automatically adds the node pool name as a label to make this easier).

Another way is to follow the tutorial for [Migrating workloads to different machine types](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool), which describes how to cordon / drain nodes to shift workloads to the new node pool.

Finally, you can just use GKE to delete your old node pool. GKE will automatically drain nodes prior to deleting them, which will cause your workload to shift to the new pool without you needing to run any extra commands yourself.

Comment: Oh I feel dumb. So if I attach a new node pool to my cluster and just delete the existing one GKE will drain them one by one and move them over? Will it ensure there is always a node running so there is no outage? does it take the rolling update settings into account when doing this operation?

Comment: Yes, if you attach a new node pool and delete the old one the workload will migrate over. There are some caveats though. Even though the old nodes will be drained, if you want to ensure application uptime you should look into pod disruption budgets to ensure that the rate of draining doesn't leave all replicas of a single app down at the same time. And if you have applied labels to pod selectors or taints to nodes it's possible that the workloads will all go into a pending state instead of being moved over. But generally it should just work without much fuss.

Comment: GKE won't ensure that there is always a node running if you delete a node pool. But if you upgrade a node pool in place it will ensure that there is always a node running. If by "node" you mean "pod" then see above about pod disruption budgets.

Comment: The docs for pod disruption budgets are at: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/disruptions/

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
kubectl drain <node_name>
```

in order to move all pods from a specific node to other nodes

Comment: The question was about moving pods from 1 node pool to another node pool. Not between nodes within one node pool.

Comment: This is a valid answer - just did this to drain old nodes on an old node pool and move pods to a new node pool.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create or update an existing node pool to add `taint` and then update the manifest of the pod you want to move with `tolerations`. This ensures that only the pod you are interested to move, moves but not others.

Refer this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/node-taints) for more detail.