# Move GKE applications from one node-pool to another

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm changing instance type of GKE cluster nodes from x to y, I have made new node-pool with the y instances all good but how do I move all the helm applications from one node-pool to the new one ?

Comment: Seems like you are looking for an option to [migrate the workloads](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/migrating-node-pool). A similar concern is discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56611184/how-do-i-move-pods-to-a-new-node-pool-instance-group) which I would recommend you to refer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your node pools `label`s, e.g `node-pool-type = old` and `node-pool-type = new`. In your pod definition, include `match-labels = new` in `spec.selector` and restart your pods.

Comment: yea that works, I also just created new node-pool and deleted the old one